# Dynamic query to read XML file using OpenRowSet executes manually but not with SP_Execute

Tags: sql, xml, file, openrowset, dynamicquery

This gives me a valid query which works:

```
:setvar StreamsLocalFolder 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT MyFile.BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + 
$(StreamsLocalFolder) + '\path.xml' + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS MyFile'
SELECT @sql
```

But this doesn't execute, wonder why:

```
:setvar StreamsLocalFolder 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app'

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT MyFile.BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + 
$(StreamsLocalFolder) + '\path.xml' + ''', SINGLE_CLOB) AS MyFile'
sp_execute @sql
```

Comment: sp_execute is a stored procedure in the SQL Sever and either it is not installed or you do not have permission to run the stored procedure.  I think you want sp_executeSQL : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Not sure if you're `:setvar` and '$' could be causing an issue, try using `declare`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work

```
sp_execute @sql
```

But this works

```
exec (@sql)
```